# How to get values in Razor View ASP NET CORE 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I working on Invoice Function . I create a seletec box to select the product i want to invoice.Here my razor view

```
IEnumerable<ProductItem> lstProduct = ViewBag.ListProduct as IEnumerable<ProductItem>

<select class="ddlProduct" name="ddlProduct">
    @foreach (var item in lstProduct)
    {
        <option value="@item.ProductItemsId"> @item.Product.ProductName</option>
    }
</select>
   <select class="ddlSize" name="ddlSize">
       @{
          
           var list = lstSize.Where(n => n.ProductItemsId == selectedProductId);
           foreach (var item in list)
           {
               <option value="@item.ProductItemsId"> @item.Size.SizeName</option>
           }
       }
   </select>
   <select class="ddlColor" name="">
       @foreach (var item in lstColor)
       {
           <option value="@item.ProductItemsId"> @item.Colors.ColorName</option>
       }
   </select>
```

The website will be like this [image]

I want when a user changes a product, the color and size will also change accordingly the product id of that product. My design database [image]

So there is anyway that i can get the productItemsID and pass to Size select box and Color
to get corresponding products

I have javascript many way but it wont work. Does anyone got solution ? I really appreciate your contribution

Comment: Your requirement can be sum up as: when the option of the dropdown changes, the following select drop down fields shall change the options based on the current selected option right? Then we need to add event listener for the onchange event, then query the database for the current selection and then change the following dropdowns.

Comment: right! Can u give me instructions please

Comment: I'm writing  a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my controller:

```
public IActionResult Product()
{
    ProductViewModel model = new ProductViewModel
    {
        Products = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "air force 1" },
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "air force 25" }
        },

        Sizes = new List<Size> {
            new Size { Id = 40, Name="40",ProductId = 1},
            new Size { Id = 41, Name="41",ProductId = 1},
            new Size { Id = 42, Name="42",ProductId = 1}
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}

public List<Size> getSizes(int id)
{
    var res = new List<Size>();
    if (id == 1)
    {
        return new List<Size> {
            new Size { Id = 40, Name="40",ProductId = 1},
            new Size { Id = 41, Name="41",ProductId = 1},
            new Size { Id = 42, Name="42",ProductId = 1}
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return new List<Size> {
            new Size { Id = 33, Name="33",ProductId = 2},
            new Size { Id = 35, Name="35",ProductId = 2},
        };
    }
}
```

View code

```
@model WebAppMvc.Models.ProductViewModel

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ProductId" class="control-label"></label>
    <select id="selectProduct" class="form-control" asp-for="ProductId"
            asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Products, nameof(Product.Id), nameof(Product.Name)))">
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="ProductId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SizeId" class="control-label"></label>
    <select id="selectSize" class="form-control" asp-for="SizeId"
            asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Sizes, nameof(Size.Id), nameof(Size.Name)))">
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="SizeId"></span>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $('#selectProduct').change(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            $('#selectSize').empty();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Hello/getSizes?id=' + id,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.info(result);
                    $.each(result, function (i, data) {
                        console.info(i);
                        console.info(data);
                        $('#selectSize').append('<option value=' + data.id + '>' + data.name + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

My Model:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SizeId { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Size> Sizes { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Size
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

[image]